# Using induction to prove lease common multiple?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to prove by induction on $m$ that

> $$\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots,a_m)=a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots a_m$$
>   if and only if $\gcd(a_i,a_j)=1$ for any $i\ne j$

**My Attempt:**
$\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots,a_m)=a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots a_m$.
I start by letting $m=2$, $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)=ab$, then $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ since $\mathrm{lcm}(ab) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$.

Consider the $m+1$ case

$$\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_m,a_{m+1})=a_1a_2\ldots a_{m+1}=\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)a_{m+1}$$
by inductive hypothesis.

But, how can I show that if this were true, then $\gcd(a_i,a_j)=1$ for any $i\ne j$?

Comment: I've taken the time to make your post more readable using MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: $\text{lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_n,a_{n+1})=\text{lcm}(\text{lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_n),a_{n+1})$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
See that
$$\gcd(ab,c) \ge \gcd(a,c)$$

Comment: hmm;so gcd(a1a2a3a4..am , am+1) > gcd(a,am+1).?

Comment: $\ge$, not $>$. But yes $\gcd(a_1 a_2 \ldots a_m, a_{m+1}) \ge \gcd(a_i, a_{m+1})$.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to understand how it does help, but can' think of any way that I can use this seemingly useful fact

Comment: @nancy On the other hand, $\gcd(a,b) \ge 1$. You want to prove that $\gcd(a_i, a_{m+1}) = 1$...

Comment: Why would the left side be 1?

Comment: @nancy Because you proved the $m=2$ case already.
$$\gcd(a,b) = \frac{ab}{\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)}$$